# Python: Values being assigned for wrong IF conditional

Tags: python, variables, if-statement

I was messing around with Python and was making a little planet simulator. I have one section that is supposed to receive a value and based on that value return a second value. I spent a few hours troubleshooting this, but I'm absolutely stumped. I added some print messages to help me track the values and it seems like it should be working, but isn't. I'm almost sure it is something obvious. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the code in question:

```
def assignTerrain(pType):

print("Assigning terrain values to planet type: ", planetType[pType], pType)

if pType == 0:
    print("Value 0 assigned", pType)
    return 0

if pType == 1 or 2:
    temp = random.randint(1, 11)
    print("Value %d assigned" % temp, pType)
    return temp

if pType == 3 or 4:
    print("Value 12 assigned", pType)
    return 12

print("There was an error with pType: ", pType)
```

As a sample, here is an example of the output I'm getting:

```
Assigning terrain values to planet type:  Asteroid Belt 4
Value 3 assigned 4
Assigning terrain values to planet type:  Asteroid Belt 4
Value 5 assigned 4
Assigning terrain values to planet type:  Asteroid Belt 4
Value 4 assigned 4
Assigning terrain values to planet type:  Asteroid Belt 4
Value 7 assigned 4
Assigning terrain values to planet type:  Asteroid Belt 4
Value 8 assigned 4
Assigning terrain values to planet type:  Asteroid Belt 4
Value 2 assigned 4
Assigning terrain values to planet type:  Asteroid Belt 4
Value 4 assigned 4
Assigning terrain values to planet type:  Asteroid Belt 4
Value 1 assigned 4
Assigning terrain values to planet type:  Asteroid Belt 4
Value 9 assigned 4
Assigning terrain values to planet type:  Asteroid Belt 4
Value 8 assigned 4
```

It seems to me that pType 4 should be skipping the first two IF statements and receive a value from the third, but it looks like it is getting caught by the 1 or 2. Any thoughts?

Comment: Instead of `if pType == 1 or 2` try `if pType in (1, 2)` or `if pType == 1 or pType == 2`.  Comparators in Python don't work the way you are thinking they do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of if

```
pType == 1 or 2
```

try

```
if pType in (1, 2)
```

or

```
if pType == 1 or pType == 2.
```

Comparators in Python don't work the way you are thinking they do.  What you are doing actually evaluates to

```
if ((pType == 1) or (4))
```

Which, since 4 is truthy, is always True.

Comment: Thank you. I feel so sheepish! I remember thinking that isn't how I'm used to IF working and thought I'd try it new, but somehow never thought to use a more traditional approach. I appreciate your concise and helpful answer.

Answer (score 2):

The expression `pType == 1 or 2` is the logical union of the two expressions `pType == 1`, which could be `True` or `False`, and `2`, which is always `True` to Python. Thus, the expression `pType == 1 or 2` is always `True` regardless of the value of `pType`.